# Which Python package is suitable for finding the optimal non dominated set in multiobjective optimization?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, multi-objective-optimization

I would like to know how to use pyhon or Cplex or both for finding the whole optimal pareto front for a biobjective mixed integer linear programming problem?

Comment: There is a way to solve this using a series of MIP problems (one MIP per point). See: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221703002558